# Play Store: Do we need to pay Google if the app is free but the service api is paid

Tags: google-play

We have developed an android app, which we wanted to upload it to google play store and have this app to be freely available for the users. This app connects to our API/service which is paid for the users like subscription based. The users are given an option where they can pay for the service. This is not really in-app purchase.

My question is do we need to pay google if the app is free but the service for the app is paid.? Amazon app is free on playstore but the products in app are sold via different payment methods which no where connect to google. I am not sure, if amazon pays to google for such service.

Please let me know. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because developer centric questions about app store policies are off topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: This question is off-topic, but for all information about Google Play policies see the policy center: https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/ This explains that cloud software products must be paid for by Google Play App billing